# Should the Xcode 4 workspace file be version controlled?

Tags: version-control, xcode4

I am using a workspace for a new Xcode 4 project. Should the `*.xcworkspace` file be included in the main repository (along with the source files of the project for example)?

Thanks
Ross

*btw. I am using GIT*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably yes.  The workspace is basically a set of projects, so if other developers would want to work with the same set, then you should put the workspace into version control.

If the workspace is strictly for your own use, or if there is only one project in the workspace, then maybe you don't need to put it into version control.  But that means you'd need to recreate it whenever you move to a new machine or decide to blow everything away and start from scratch.

Xcode 4 is pretty good about putting user-specific data into folders/files whose names contain the word "user" or your user name, and putting build products and temporary files somewhere outside of the source tree, so in general, I'd put everything that isn't obviously user-specific into the repository.

Comment: Shouldn't we put it as `xxx.workspace.dist` or something like that ?

Comment: FWIW, I see other people on the Internet recommended to NOT version control the workspace file. I guess my recommendation is to do whatever you find to be helpful with your specific workflow.

Comment: I meant `xxx.workspace.dist` as an example workspace to start with when you freshly clone the project. So the main workspace is not tracked but you still have starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Xcode uses some specific .gitignore settings. You might want to create a sample project, letting Xcode use Git (it's in the project save-as dialog that's the last step of creating a new project), then check out the .gitignore in its root.

Comment: It actually looks like Xcode now only adds 2 things to info/exclude, not ignore. `.DS_Store` & `UserInterface.xcuserstate` These two things don't seem terribly informative. (Xcode 4.3.2)

Comment: The xcuserstate thing seems to be the current status of the workspace UI (e.g., which folders are expanded in the project navigator). If you don't .gitignore those, you will have a change (and hence,  a need to commit) every time you touch the Xcode UI, even if you don't modify any code.